# why div and ul width and height are different from normal

Tags: html, css, xhtml

This is my code:

**CSS**

```css
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
ul {
    height: 200px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
p {
    height: 200px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<p></p>
```

I want to ask why the width and height are different from normal(paragraph and division) even if the width and height i set is the same?

Comment: its all the same for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ucadd/ it's probably the browser you're using. what browser are you using?

Comment: @kennypu turn off `Normalized CSS`

Comment: it's different because the ul has default styling set from the browser, in this case a border and padding. this is one of the reasons why you should use a reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many browsers put internal padding on `ul` tags by default.

You would need to override this:

**CSS**

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
ul {
    height: 200px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
p {
    height: 200px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0px;
}​
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xDmQH/)**

Answer (score 0):

you might just need to do a css reset:

```
/**
 * Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0 (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)
 * http://cssreset.com
 */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Or for now you can just add to all your css:

`html, body, div, ul, li, p { margin:0; padding:0;}`

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have default styling. In the case of ordered/unordered lists, some browsers add left margin while some add left padding

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
ul {
-webkit-padding-start: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
}
```

You can open Developer Tool and see User Agent Stylesheet defined by browser and override anything you want.